# Como fazer uma conexão Delphi-Oracle sem Client Oracle

Tags: delphi, oracle

Tenho um aplicativo que foi desenvolvido numa época que tínhamos um sistema cliente-servidor , com isto havia sempre um client Oracle em cada máquina, agora temos um sistema 3 camadas e não temos mais este Client.

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma conexão Delphi-Oracle sem Client Oracle

Versões

Delphi : Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010

Oracle : Versão 11g

Desde já grato

Comment: Não tem como. Você precisa do client do Oracle para conectar ao Oracle (bem como a qualquer outro banco, embora o client do SQL Server geralmente já esteja disponível no Windows). Eventualmente você não precisa instalar aquela tonelada de software da Oracle só pra poder conectar ao banco - um colega meu identificou uma vez uma meia dúzia de arquivos que era necessário ter na máquina e alguns precisava registrar no Windows - mas alguma biblioteca no lado do cliente você vai precisar sempre.

Comment: Beleza, vou pensar um caminho alternativo.